# Process login vs user login

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, process, users, login

In a Ubuntu 14.04 system, `who` has the following output:

```
user1   :0           2016-05-02 14:49 (:0)
user1   pts/4        2016-05-02 15:10 (:0)
```

So apparently just the `pts/4` is used. But, for example, `sudo fuser /dev/pts/1` produces as output `2573`, which is `cupsd`. So, that terminal is used too, by a process.

In order to use a terminal, one has to make a login. `user1` has logged in;

- did processes like `cups` make a login as well?
- If yes, what is the difference between a regular user login and a *process* login? It does not appear in `who`.

Comment: You don't need  to login to get a terminal. Every `xterm` window gets a terminal. But you just login once on the display.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe this is another question. You are right. But how is it possible to log in just once, and then have the possibility to open a lot of terminals without credentials?

Comment: There's little difference between opening terminals and opening other types of communication streams, like pipes and sockets.

Comment: What I think you're really asking is how do programs like xterm get their terminal listed by the "who" command if they don't require authentication, is that right?

Comment: I think the answer is that the file `/var/run/utmp` is writable by the `utmp` group, and these programs are set-GID to that group, so they can add update it.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for the delay. The question you guessed is one of mine. I was only able to see that executables like `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` belong to the user `root` and to the group `root`: I didn't see they belong to the `utmp` group. Anyway, I made a more specific question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282012/when-opening-a-terminal-does-not-require-a-login).

Comment: If it's set-uid to root then it can write to anything. The `utmp` group is for programs that don't need any other special privileges.

Comment: Which question is the one I guessed? I don't see references to other questions here.

Comment: @Barmar This was the question: "What I think you're really asking is how do programs like xterm get their terminal listed by the "who" command if they don't require authentication, is that right?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any program can allocate a pseudo-terminal, it doesn't have to involve a login. It's just another form of inter-process communication, which is useful if the application needs to emulate a terminal.

An example is the `Expect` program. It allocates a pseudo-terminal when it spawns a program, so that the program will act as if it's being run interactively by a user.

As for showing up in the `who` output, the program needs to be set-UID to `root` or set-GID to `utmp` to be able to update the `/var/run/utmp` file that lists which user is logged into each terminal. This is generally only done for programs that create interactive logins, like `login`, `gnome-terminal, or`xterm`.